# How to trigger filter function with parameters from a different controller

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

> Background:

I switched from a filter inside my ng-repeat to a filter that I call manually because the filtered objects were too big and too many, causing immense performance issues when the filter function was constantly called.
Now I have to change the architecture and the first problem I ran into is the following...

> Problem:

A project might be changed when executing a process inside of a different controller so I need to execute the filter function (`getProjects`) again after that.
I thought about moving the filter function to a Service class, in order to be able to call it from different controllers. But the problem then is, that I need the search field value (`searchText`) as parameter of the filter function - but that field is only accessible inside of the original controller.

I'm looking for an "clean" solution here - e.g. turning the searchfield into some kind of global rootscope variable doesn't sound right to me...but feel free to give me your opinion on how this is best solved.

Here's a minified example:
https://jsfiddle.net/wba2s4ey/
I already moved the filter function to the Service Class but I don't know how to pass the `query` value from the second controller and I don't think that's very clean.

Comment: Why put a filter in a service instead of just writing it as a filter? The [AngularJS docs for Filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) has an example of writing a custom filter.

Comment: @Lex Because of performance -  filters in the DOM are slower than running filters in JavaScript

Comment: I see. Sounds like your projects collection should be stored in the service so that changes to its objects in one controller will be reflected in the other controller.

Comment: @Lex yes, the projects collection is already there

Comment: Store the filtered collection and the filter criteria in the service as well then. If changes are made to an object in the collection you simply call a service method to rebuild the filtered collection no matter which controller you are in when the change is made.

Comment: @Lex ah, I think I get it - you gave me the idea for the solution - thank you!!!
I could just change the search parameter in the service through an "onChange" function of the html input element.

Comment: @Lex see my solution - is this how you would've done it? Is there a better way not to expose the Service?

Comment: I think the way you did it is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it: https://jsfiddle.net/9j7stgo6/
I just think it's ugly that I have to directly use the Service inside of the html but I can't think of a better way. I previously tried declaring `this.updateFilter = this.HelperService.updateFilter;` in the `ControllerOne`, but it doesn't have the correct `this` then and can't find the method `updateProjects`.